# Find a substring between two optional markers

Tags: regex, string

I was trying to extract substrings from a string of the following form:

```
dest=comp;jump
```

I'm looking for a regexp to retrieve `comp`, but both `dest` and `jump` are optional, in which case `=` or `;` is ommitted. So these are all valid configurations:

```
dest=comp;jump
dest=comp
comp;jump
comp
```

`dest`, `comp` and `jump` are arbitrary strings, but do not contain equality signs nor semicolons.

What I managed to come up with is the following:
    `(?:=)([^;=]*)(?:;)`
Unfortunately, it doesn't work when either `dest` or `jump` is ommitted.

Comment: Is there other string to extract instead of `comp` only ?

Comment: Can `comp` contain `=` or `;`?

Comment: Comp doesn't contain semi-colons or equality signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(?:.*=|^)([^;]+)(?:;|$)
```

The string you're searching is in group 1.

Comment: Won't work in this case: `dest=comp`: http://rubular.com/r/mBXmIiSZZw

Answer (score 0):

If the whole line has to have that form, this should do:

```
if line.chomp =~ /\A(?:[^;=]+=)?([^=;]+)(?:;[^;=]+)?\z/
  puts $1
end
```

This will skip ill-formed lines like

```
"dest=dest=comp;jump;jump"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to make it all happen inside a single regular expression. That path makes it harder to read and maintain. Instead I'd break it into more atomic tests using `case`/`when` statements:

If you only want `comp` I'd use:

```
array = %w[
  dest=comp;jump
  dest=comp
  comp;jump
  comp
].map{ |str|

  case str
  when /.+=(.+);/, /=(.+)/, /(.+);/
    $1
  else
    str 
  end

}

array 
# => ["comp", "comp", "comp", "comp"]
```

The `when` clause breaks the complexity down into three small tests, each of them very easy to understand:

1. Does the string have both `'='` and `';'`? Then return the substring between those two characters.
2. Does the string have `'='`? Then return the last word.
3. Does the string have `';'`? Then return the first word.
4. Return the word.

If you need to know *which* of your terms are being returned then a bit more code is needed:

```
%w[
  dest=comp;jump
  dest=comp
  comp;jump
  comp
].each{ |str|

  dest, comp, jump = case str
                     when /(.+)=(.+);(.+)/
                       [$1, $2, $3]
                     when /(.+)=(.+)/
                       [$1, $2, nil]
                     when /(.+);(.+)/
                       [nil, $1, $2]
                     else
                       [nil, str, nil]
                     end

  puts 'dest="%s" comp="%s" jump="%s"' % [dest, comp, jump]
}

# >> dest="dest" comp="comp" jump="jump"
# >> dest="dest" comp="comp" jump=""
# >> dest="" comp="comp" jump="jump"
# >> dest="" comp="comp" jump=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just try to split the expression into two, makes it easier to understand what is happening:

```
string = 'dest=comp;jump'
trimming_regexp = [/.*=/, /;.*/]
trimming_regexp.each{|exp| string.slice!(exp)}
```